# DVI Pins electric current

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, dvi

I have a desktop computer and I am connecting the video output from the motherboard via a DVI-D (Dual link) cable. My question is that while the computer is switched on and I touch the pins of the DVI cable - is it strong enough to feel the current. If I stand barefoot on the ground and hold my finger across the DVI pins connected to the motherboard on a powered computer - I am able to feel a slight electric current so is this normal ? The intensity is not very strong - i can stay in contact for about 1 second after which involuntarily I break contact and there is no numbness or anything. Also it's practically nil when i'm not barefoot.
The point is - is this normal ? No other components giving any form of current externally.
Otherwise I would need my PSU and grounding investigated.

Comment: Thanks for your responses - general consensus is that it should be barely detectable with no twitching or numbness.
Unfortunately while the current i'm feeling barefoot is not even enough to be even called a mild shock - it's enough to make me involuntarily twitch my finger away from the pins. 

Since this does not appear to be normal, I'm concluding there is a tiny leakage somewhere although I've no idea where. Will get components investigated with a multimeter properly. Electrician checked grounding and told me it was fine but you never know the quality of construction (in India).

Answer (score 1):

You're effectively shorting the pins, so I would assume this is normal seeing as you are touching an electrical component and completing multiple circuits.

I would ask though, why are you trying to electrocute yourself? Surely you know touching anywhere inside a computer while it's turned on is highly likely to damage you and your computer?? The same as touching any bare electrical components in any item would. You're question practically says 'If I put my hand over a naked flame, it hurts. Is this normal or should I look into acquiring a cold flame?' Just don't do it in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I have a follow-up question... The reason is that I'm wondering if the current in the DVI cable connected to a powered mobo is enough to be detected by a barefoot human being. Afaik, the signal current is at just 5V and I don't know if that can be felt if you short the pins.

Why am I doing this - well recently there has been some unusual activity regarding tiny shocks from my "assembled" PC. I've had trouble root-causing it and so now I'm not at all sure if the current in the DVI connector is expected behavior or not. Rest assured I'm not going to try anything further.

Comment: 50mA at 5v could just barely be detected.

Comment: That makes more sense. Your first question read as if you were just randomly trying to generate electric shocks for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 1):

DVI is a 5V system. Usually you don't feel 5V as more than a slight tingle if even that. If you feel any numbness or twitches in muscles, it's not from the DVI.

Most likely the power-supply is badly insulated and grounded. If the socket you use does not have protected grounding, some leakage current can be grounded through you. This was a usual problem with BNC-network cards in the 90's. Also the same effect happens with television antennae.